# css border-bottom iexplorer

Tags: html, css, html-table

css:

```
.item_fact{
     border-bottom:#CCCCCC 1px solid;
}
```

html:

```
<table>
  <tr class="item_fact">
    <td> hello </td>
    <td> world </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

IE7 does not display the border-bottom, but Firefox and Chrome does!
How can I hack this css?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the correct css syntax would be:

border-bottom: size style color;

So, in your case:

border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;

**edit**: actually, it seems TR doesn't act like it 'contains' the TD elements in IE7. One trick you can do is have the table collapse borders, then apply all TDs under .item_fact to have the border-bottom themselves.

Like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.item_fact td {
     border-bottom:1px solid #CCCCCC;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
  <tr class="item_fact">
    <td> hello </td>
    <td> world </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Borders on rows are not supported in IE/css. You need to border the cells.

```
.item_fact td {
  border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
}
```